# filling the area between two curves in 3d using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, interpolation

I have two 3d curve (actually a 2d curves in `x` and `z` with a fixed `y` axis) that I want to fill the area between them. The curves don't share the same `x` values, so I used `scipy.interpoulate.intrp1d` to generate same `x` values. Now I understand I should use `scipy.interpulate.griddata` to generate a a grid to be plotted, but I can't figure out how to do this. `griddata` expects to get `(n,D)` coordinates points and `n` values, while what I have is `n` coordinate points and `2n` values. How can I generate my grid then?

Comment: I think it would greately help, if you included a self contained piece of code. Why would you need griddata if your problem is actually a 1D problem? Maybe you first try a solution in 1D and and then add another dimension. If that does not work, you can update your question with the code you tried.

Comment: Something like the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33641551)? As for the griddata, have you seen the [examples](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html)? And if you generated data for, lets say, the second function using interpolation and the `x` values of the first function, can't you just use those `x` values to plot both curves?