# How to fill area under 3D circular line plot in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, visualization

Please advise how to best fill in the area under a 3D line plot. For example, I'd like to fill in the area between z=0 and z-location given in the line plot below. I have not been able to do this with polygons...

[image]

```
plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
zline = Phi_scaled[1,0:200] #This could be any set of random values/is not a function of x or y position
theta = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,200)
xline = np.cos(theta)
yline = np.sin(theta)
#ax.plot3D(xline, yline, zline, 'gray')
ax.plot(xline,yline,zline,label="line plot")`
```

Comment: Can you provide the code with which you have obtained the plot please ?

Comment: plt.figure()
    ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
    zline = Phi_scaled[1,0:200] # this could be any function/is not related to x or y values - feel free to make zline = to a random set of numbers
    theta = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,200)
    xline = np.cos(theta)
    yline = np.sin(theta)
    ax.plot(xline,yline,zline,label="line plot")

Comment: Did you look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33641551/vertically-fill-3d-matplotlib-plot)? (There is a comment about a small change for Python3)

Comment: This is perfect, thanks!